# Spark 2.2.2: CountVectorizerModel Index 24691 out of bounds for vector of size 23262

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Hello all and have a lovely day. I would like some help according to your experience. I am trying to convert a collection of text documents to vectors of token counts based on a custom vocabulary with an array size of 24693 with **CountVectorizerModel**

**Here is the simple code**

```
CountVectorizerModel cvm2 = new CountVectorizerModel(vocabulary)
                .setInputCol(NEXT)
                .setOutputCol(NEXT_RAW_FEATURES);
        cvm2.transform(dataset).show(false);
```

**Here is my entire exception:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$8: (array<string>) => vector)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
ERROR   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
----------------------
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Index 24691 out of bounds for vector of size 23262
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector.<init>(Vectors.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors$.sparse(Vectors.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel$$anonfun$8.apply(CountVectorizer.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel$$anonfun$8.apply(CountVectorizer.scala:248)
    ... 16 more
```

**Why i got**

```
Index 24691 out of bounds for vector of size 23262
```

**and how can i fix it? Do i need to adapt**

```
 setMinTF()
```

With a prefix size. I don't know what to do, so i am stack here. Basically, i cannot understand why does this happen and how to fix it. I would appreciate if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Your vocab array contains duplicates. You need to remove duplicates with the array